# When I try to debug a VS solution I get an error about 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, azure, dropbox, azure-compute-emulator

I am using VS 2010, trying to debug (F5) a solution that is saved in a shared Dropbox folder, but I get the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics' or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.

If it's worth noting - my partner is the one who created the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an annoying bug in VS when working in a shared folder (when you didn't create the solution yourself). Try to clean the project. This might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have installed Azure Visual Studio Tools?
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/downloads/

Answer (score 0):

The dll for the azure sdk is probably not located in the dropbox folder. It is usually installed on the local drive.

You can either install your own, as long as the path is exactly the same (not recommended in case you guys decided to upgrade, then you would both need to remember to), or copy the dll into the dropbox folder and re-add it in the solution, so that you both are pointing at the same one.

Comment: Actually it is in the Dropbox folder. I am wondering whether there might be a problem with the fact that me and my partner has different dropbox paths (for example mine it under "c:\users\yoni\dropbox" and his is under "d:\dropbox\..."

Comment: That would do it. As far as I know, VS is looking at the path and mapping it on your local machine. So it is looking in the wrong place.

Comment: Check the solution file in a text editor, if the file paths are not relative, make them so

Comment: I wasn't aware you could do that. Yossi's fix should clear your problem.